# Slide up and remove submenus with jQuery

Tags: jquery, submenu

here is the code in question:

```
            $('a.delete').click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var parent = $(this).parent();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: 'deletemenu.php',
                data: 'ajax=1&delete=' + parent.attr('id').replace('menu-',''),
                beforeSend: function() {
                parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
            },
                    success: function() {

                    parent.slideUp(300,function() {
                        parent.remove();
                    });

                    $('.menusub').slideUp(300,function() {
                        $('.menusub').remove();
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Ok, what i want to do is slideUp and remove all submenu's which are under a specific menu (when deleting this menu). Right now i have `$('.menusub').slideUp(300,function() {
                            $('.menusub').remove();
                        });`. To achieve this. The problem with this code, ofcourse, is that it will make all submenu's (which have the menusub class) disappear. How can i make sure that only the submenu's under the specific menu will disappear?

By the way, this is the code to view the menu's

```
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Menu") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo '<div class="menu" id="menu-',$row['menu_id'],'">';
            echo $row['menu_name']. " - ". $row['menu_weight']. "<a class='delete' href='?delete=".$row['menu_id']."'> delete</a>";
            echo '</div>';

            $sub = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM SubMenu INNER JOIN Menu WHERE SubMenu.menu_id = Menu.menu_id AND Menu.Menu_id = ".$row['menu_id']."") or die(mysql_error());
            while($subrow = mysql_fetch_array($sub)){
                echo '<div class="menusub" id="menusub-',$subrow['submenu_id'],'">';
                echo "-- ".$subrow['submenu_name']." - ".$subrow['submenu_weight']."<a class='deletesub' href='?deletesub=".$subrow['submenu_id']."'> delete</a><br/>";
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }`
```

Tnx for replying!

Comment: Please post your html code to reveal how your `menu is structured`.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

Change :

```
$('#menusub-').slideUp(300,function() {
    $('.menusub').remove();
});
```

To:

```
var rowid = parent.attr('id').split('-')[1];
$('#menusub-'+rowid).slideUp(300,function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

**Edit:**
A suggestion, add an attribute `rel` to the submenus like this:

```
rel="$row['menu_id']"
```

and make your script like:

```
$('a.delete').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.slideUp(300,function() {
        parent.remove();
});

var id = parent.attr('id').split('-')[1];
$('div.submenu').each(function(index, element) {
    $this = $(this);
    if($this.attr('rel') == id) {
        $this.slideUp(300,function() {
            $this.remove();
        });
    }
    });

});
```

Comment: Good idea! With the rel attribute. Anyway it still doesn't work.

Comment: When i try to alert my rel like this: `var print = $('.menusub').attr('rel');` it says undefined, which is strange. It can't seem to find the rel.

Comment: Well i've fixed the rel issue. But there's one thing left. When i delete a menu with submenu's above another menu with submenu's, the script removes also the submenu's of the menu which is under that menu.